# Is it possible to get the list of pages and devices in a single GA4 v1beta request?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I'm having to make 2 `runRealtimeReport` requests, one to get the device category and another to get the list of the most accessed pages.

What I would like to get is the general amount of hits to the site via `mobile`, `desktop` and `tablet`, but including the two dimensions, return the pages and the device category of each access.

If I include the `deviceCategory` and `unifiedScreenName` dimensions in the same request, the data is grouped as shown in the example below:

**Request body:**

```
{
  "metrics": [
    {
      "name": "activeUsers"
    }
  ],
  "dimensions": [
    {
      "name": "deviceCategory"
    },
    {
      "name": "unifiedScreenName"
    }
  ],
  "limit": 2
}
```

**Response:**

```
{
    "dimensionHeaders": [
        {
            "name": "deviceCategory"
        },
        {
            "name": "unifiedScreenName"
        }
    ],
    "metricHeaders": [
        {
            "name": "activeUsers",
            "type": "TYPE_INTEGER"
        }
    ],
    "rows": [
        {
            "dimensionValues": [
                {
                    "value": "mobile"
                },
                {
                    "value": "Title page 01"
                }
            ],
            "metricValues": [
                {
                    "value": "9"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "dimensionValues": [
                {
                    "value": "mobile"
                },
                {
                    "value": "Title Page 2"
                }
            ],
            "metricValues": [
                {
                    "value": "3"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "rowCount": 16,
    "kind": "analyticsData#runRealtimeReport"
}
```

Comment: There is no way other than sending separate request for each dimension.